# ordering online using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to order some rope online, by using excel.
I have written this piece of code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
      IE.Visible = True
      IE.navigate ("https://www.paracord.eu/ppm-touw-10mm-neon-orange")
      Do
            If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
                Exit Do
            Else
               DoEvents
           End If
      Loop

      IE.Document.Forms(0).all("Qty").Value = "10"

      IE.Document.Forms(0).submit
      Do
            If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
                Exit Do
            Else
               DoEvents
           End If
      Loop
End Sub
```

It will open the website, but i cant get it to fill in the "10" as an order. Does anyone know what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like it might be time to use a modern programming language with a library designed for this purpose. https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Comment: html-agility, really? Has it had an upgrade? You'd be better with a selenium flavour e.g. python selenium,

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1) Use a proper page load wait

```
Do:DoEvents:Loop While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
```

Then

2) Use id for amount

either

```
ie.document.querySelector("#qty").value = 10
```

or

```
ie.document.querySelector("#qty").setAttribute "value",  10
```

or even

```
ie.document.parentwindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#qty').setAttribute('value',  10);"
```

You could alternatively monitor the `value` attribute value, of `ie.document.querySelector("#qty")`,  and loop clicking the + button until you reach you target value

You can click the + with

```
ie.document.querySelector("#plus").click
```

3) Then submit with:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#product-addtocart-button").click
```